# Backbone.js: Updating model attributes inside event does not persist

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following in my `App.addInitializer`

```
App.addInitializer(function () {
   // Collection Map for dynamic slide-in menus
   var map = {
       'groups': {
           'view': GroupsCollectionView,
           'collection': GroupsCollection,
           'title': "Choose Groups"
       }
   };

   var menuModel = new MenuModel({
           id: 'segments-are-cool',
           mode: 'list'
       }),
       menuView = new MenuView({model: menuModel});

    eventer.on('menu-open', function(type){
        var collectionType = new map[type].collection,
            viewType = new map[type].view({collection: collectionType}),
            title = map[type].title;

        menuView.model.set({type: type, title: title});
        menuView.content.show(viewType);
    });

    App.menu.show(menuView);
});
```

For some reason when I set the `type` and `title` on the model, when my view is displayed, they are not shown to what I set them too (the default value shows up).

I'm a `backbone.js` newb, so my apologies on my ignorance

Comment: Where are you triggering the `menu-open` event for `eventer`? It would look like `eventer.trigger('menu-open', yourtype);`.

Comment: Backbone doesn't attach model with view, that means changes in model doesn't reflect in the view. In other words, backbone natively (there are plugins of course) doesn't support model-view binding. One quick solution would be to re-render the view, once the model is changed.

Answer (score 0):

As coding_idiot explained in the comments, Backbone (unlike say Angular) does not automatically update `View`s when their `Model`s change.  While this is slightly less convenient, it gives you much greater control over what happens.

In general most Backbone developers (as coding_idiot suggested) simply invoke `View.render` after a `Model` changes.  You could even automate this by having the `View` call `this.model.listenTo('change', this.render);` inside its `initialize` method.

Alternatively you could use a library like Epoxy (http://epoxyjs.org/) to further automate your data binding, but personally I wouldn't recommend it just because I think there's a lot of value to having exact control over when and what you re-render.